# How do I manually edit eclipse code formatting preferences?

Tags: eclipse

Due to a bug in Eclipse, every time I try to change the Code Formatting preferences, Eclipse crashes. Thus, I cannot edit code formatting preferences via Eclipse's built in window editor. These are workspace specific preferences. Where can I find the file to edit the preferences manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the code format profiles are stored in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` file

This is a Java properties format file. The code formatter settings are in the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.formatterprofiles` property. The value is an XML object. This is going to be hard to edit!

Comment: What's the difference between this and `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`?

Comment: It looks like `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` contains the formatter preferences which are current active and `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` contains all the different formatter profiles.